# Comunicación entre Activity y Fragment

Tags: java, android, activity

estoy intentando hacer que mi app detecte cuándo el usuario se queda sin internet utilizando un BroadcastReceiver, pero no logro comunicar al fragmento el cambio del estado de red.

Mi pregunta es, ¿cómo puedo notificar al fragmento el cambio en el estado de red?

Este ese método que utilizo para verificar la conexión:

```
   private void chequeoInternet() {
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(BroadcastNetwork.NETWORK_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            boolean isNetworkAvailable = intent.getBooleanExtra(BroadcastNetwork.IS_NETWORK_AVAILABLE, false);
            String networkStatus = isNetworkAvailable ? "Conectado" : "Desconectado";

            if(!isNetworkAvailable)
            {

                    //Notificar al fragment

            }

            Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.contenedor), "Estado Conexión: " + networkStatus, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }, intentFilter);
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con un metodo publico dentro del fragment y almacenando en una variable global en el activity el fragment.

Suponiendo que tu fragment lo almacenaste en una variable llamada mCurrentFragment:

```
    if(!isNetworkAvailable){
        if(mCurrentFragment instanceof MyFragment){
            ((MyFragment) mCurrentFragment).notifyInternetConnection();
        }
    }
```

O si utilizaste el FragmentManager con el stack entonces obten el fragment actual y has lo siguiente:

```
if(!isNetworkAvailable){
        Fragment mCurrentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.tu_container);
        if(mCurrentFRagment instanceof MyFragment){
            ((MyFragment) mCurrentFragment).notifyInternetConnection();
        }
    }
```

Y en tu Fragment (en mi ejemplo MyFragment) agrega el metodo notifyInternetConnection():

```
 public void notifyInternetConnection(){
    //Accion
 }
```